# Which coin to mine with CPU long-term

Tags: mining-profitability, altcoin, cpu

I have a machine with 48 CPU cores, running Linux. I would like to mine for a coin, not to sell immediately, but in several months when the value has increased (hopefully).

I don't want to keep changing every day, so what coin would be best, and why? I realise this involves predicting the future, but would like to hear various views.

Comment: Why do you have a machine with 48 CPU cores?

Comment: Most probably because it is fun, or he is in some research university and want to abuse his possibility :-)

Comment: http://www.247techblog.com/easiest-cryptocurrency-mine-laptop-computer-datacoin-cpu-mining-currency/

Answer (score 2):

Generally, CPU mining isn't worth the electricity consumes.  However, we will assume that you've got some adequately efficient cores.
If you are going to do CPU mining, you might have more luck using a scrypt based fork of bitcoin, such as tenebrix, litecoin, or fairbrix.
Because the effectiveness of a setup can vary, as well as the price of various cryptocurrencies, your best bet is to do your own experimentation:

 
For each coin:

1. Mine for an hour or so, and determine your average mining rate
2. Look up the current difficulty of that coin
3. Use something like the [Bitcoin Mining Calculator](http://www.alloscomp.com/bitcoin/calculator.php) to determine how much you stand to make
4. Convert it into $ per day or something similar

You would then compare the profitability of the various coins and choose which is best.

Alternatively, if you wish to assume that scrypt is best for your setup, and that your hashrate will be identical across different scrypt-based coins, you can use [CoinWarz](http://www.coinwarz.com/cryptocurrency) to determine the best coin to mine (currently Fastcoin, although they rate fastcoin as having bad stability, so you may wish to drop down to digitalcoin or novacoin if you feel like you need something a little more stable.)

Comment: All scrypt-based cryptocoins use the same algo, so the hashrate will be the same. Scrypt is usually better than sha256 with CPU mining (at least using pooler's cpuminer).

Comment: You can find almost real-time comparison of all coins here: http://dustcoin.com/mining