# What coin could I mine with CPU now-a-days?

Tags: mining-profitability, cpu-mining

I have computer where I have only CPU and don't need to pay for energy. What kind of virtual currency should I mine?

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32738/i-have-free-energy-good-idea-to-mine-btc-ltc

Comment: potential duplicates: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2871/can-i-cpu-mine-others-coins-to-win-bitcoins http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11810/which-coin-to-mine-with-cpu-long-term

Comment: It would be much better, if you asked the question in a fashion that was unreliant on the current time: E.g. "How can one pick out a coin to mine with CPU only?" Also, please don't ask the same question twice, rather improve the first instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can check profitability of all the algorythms and many currencies - [CoinWarz](http://www.coinwarz.com/cryptocurrency).
Possibilities of your computer you have to check by yourself, by installing mining software and running it with wallet or conneting to crypto-mines.

Answer (score 1):

You can register an account with a multipool. This is a pool that automatically switches to the most profitable coin.

Because you are using a CPU, the only viable option would be a multipool that also (or only) mines X11 algorithm coins. This way you'll at least get something. (Mining SHA-256 coins like Bitcoin with a CPU will get you less than 40 cents after a YEAR of mining.)
Both multipool.us and coinmine.pw are multipools that mine X11 next to other algorithms.